# how to save files to azure file storage from react?

Tags: reactjs, azure

Is there a good way to save files from to Azure file storage from React?  For example, I can connect to the following Azure Storage Account url via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer:

https://my-azure-storage.file.core.windows.net/hcs-files

I see that this storage account has a "File Shares" folder in Azure but it appears that I need to create a specific instance of a file share under this folder in order to upload files so I've created a basic "my-files" file share.  Is there a way for me to upload files from React to this file share like this?:

```
const someStream = getFileStream();
azureClientLib.connect("https://my-azure-storage.file.core.windows.net/my-files");
azureClientLib.setSavePath("./group1/plan1/special-info.pdf");
azureClientLib.saveFile(someStream);
```

Comment: Are you running into any issues with the code you’ve written? Also, have you seen JavaScript SDK for Azure File Storage?

Comment: thanks gaurav - I just provided the code in my original post as theoretical example code to demo what I wanted to accomplish.  I will take a look at the JavaScript SDK for Azure File Storage that you mentioned.  thanks!